# Issues with angular ui-grid options object

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am struggling to push data to my ui-grid I set up in my angular app.

Here is what I did:

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
</div>

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

$scope.gridOptions.data = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
    }
];

}]);
```

However no data is being displayed in my grid. Anyone know why?

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/tCBB3nfsLtFhfIgKNk47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `gridOptions` object, you have to define it before assign data:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {data: []};
$scope.gridOptions.data = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
    }
];
```

The problem was that gridOptions was not defined, so it was throwing this error in the console: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of undefined`.